# Remove nodes before Adding new ones Swift

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, scnnode, coreml

I'm working on a iOS app that's supposed to recognize a number (using CoreML + Vision) on a wall and after that add several planes (number of planes depending of that room schedule(horario) ) to that same wall with various content like weekday and opening(inicio) or closing(fim) time. The problem that I'm having is that if I continue to aim the camera towards the number after the first planes were added the planes are continuously added which is not supposed to happen. I have though of something like removing all nodes/make them disappear immediately before the new ones are added or stop adding for that specific room that was already detected but feel free to think and suggest different ways!

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)
{

    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

    let dataformatter = DateFormatter()
    dataformatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

    let dataformatter_wk = DateFormatter()
    dataformatter_wk.dateFormat = "EEEE"

    var i = 0

    for horario in (self.room?.horario)!{

        //Convert Dates
        let comp_inicio: DateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: (horario.hora_ini)!)
        let comp_fim: DateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: (horario.hora_fim)!)
        let comp_wk: DateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday, .day, .month, .year, .hour, .minute], from: (horario.hora_ini)!)

        let data_inicio = Calendar.current.date(from: comp_inicio)
        let data_fim = Calendar.current.date(from: comp_fim)
        let data_wk = Calendar.current.date(from: comp_wk)

        let hora_inicio = dataformatter.string(from: data_inicio!)
        let hora_fim = dataformatter.string(from: data_fim!)
        let horario_final =  (hora_inicio + "-" + hora_fim).uppercased()

        let weekday = dataformatter_wk.string(from: data_wk!).uppercased()

        //Plane
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(0.09), height: CGFloat(0.09))
        plane.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.planeColor
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

        //Text
        let material_text = SCNMaterial()
        material_text.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black

        //Get the content from JSON
        let text_horario = SCNText(string: horario_final, extrusionDepth: 0.1)
        let text_weekday = SCNText(string: weekday, extrusionDepth: 0.1)
        let text_descr = SCNText(string: horario.descr?.uppercased() ?? 0, extrusionDepth: 0.1)

        text_weekday.materials = [material_text]
        text_descr.materials = [material_text]
        text_horario.materials = [material_text]

        let node_text_weekday = SCNNode(geometry: text_weekday)
        let node_text_horario = SCNNode(geometry: text_horario)
        let node_text_descr = SCNNode(geometry: text_descr)

        //Piones
        let piones = SCNCylinder(radius: 0.002, height: 0.005)
        let material_piones = SCNMaterial()
        material_piones.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
        piones.materials = [material_piones]
        let node_piones = SCNNode(geometry: piones)

        // 5 Get the planeAnchor positions
        let x = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.x) // Esquerda e direita
        let y = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.y) // +y = Mais perto do telemovel
        let z = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.z) // -z = Mais alto

        // Rotate and scale the nodes
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
        node_text_weekday.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
        node_text_horario.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
        node_text_descr.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
        node_text_weekday.scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.0005, y: 0.0005, z: 0.0005)
        node_text_horario.scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.0005, y: 0.0005, z: 0.0005)
        node_text_descr.scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.0007, y: 0.0007, z: 0.0007)

        // Add the nodes positions
        planeNode.position =            SCNVector3(x         + CGFloat(i%3)/10  ,y , z       + CGFloat(i/3)/10)
        node_text_weekday.position =    SCNVector3(x - 0.025 + CGFloat(i%3)/10  ,y , z       + CGFloat(i/3)/10)
        node_text_horario.position =    SCNVector3(x - 0.020 + CGFloat(i%3)/10  ,y , z+0.035 + CGFloat(i/3)/10)
        node_text_descr.position =      SCNVector3(x - 0.029 + CGFloat(i%3)/10  ,y , z-0.015 + CGFloat(i/3)/10)
        node_piones.position =          SCNVector3(x         + CGFloat(i%3)/10  ,y , z-0.035 + CGFloat(i/3)/10)


        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
        node.addChildNode(node_text_weekday)
        node.addChildNode(node_text_horario)
        node.addChildNode(node_text_descr)
        node.addChildNode(node_piones)

        //Used for positioning of the planes on the wall
        i=i+1
    }
}
```

Comment: Are all the numbers unique?

Comment: @JoshRobbins yes! All numbers are unique!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all the code, its hard to provide a proper answer.

However, there are a few things you can consider.

First off you could create a `var` called:

```
var detectedRoomNumber: Int?
```

Which would be set when the `Vision Framework` detects it.

Since you also say that each room number is unique, you can create an `Array [Int]` to store an initial reference to these e.g:

```
var roomNumbers: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Then once a number is detected by the `Vision Framework` you can set this as the `detectedRoomNumber` and remove it from the `Array` ensuring that it can only be detected once.

In addition as an additional safeguard you can store reference to each `ARPlaneAnchor`.

Each `ARPlaneAnchor` has a unique `UUID` identifier, and as such you could create some logic to ensure that if this ARPlaneAnchor has already been detected that new content won't be added e.g:

```
var roomPlanes = [UUID: ARPlaneAnchor]()
```

As such some pseudo code might look like so:

```
//---------------------------
// MARK: -  ARSCNViewDelegate
//---------------------------

extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate{

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        //1. Check To See Whether An ARPlaneAnchor Has Been Detected
        guard let roomPlaneAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

        /*
         Vision Has Detected Our Room Number, So We Check To See If Our Array Of Room Numbers Contains The Room
         We Also Check To See If The ARPlaneAnchor Has Already Been Detected
         */

        if let validRoom = detectedRoomNumber, roomNumbers.contains(validRoom), !roomPlanes.keys.contains(roomPlaneAnchor.identifier){

            //a. If Our Array Isnt Empty Get The Index Of The Room & Remove It From Our Array So It Cant Be Redected
            if roomNumbers.count != 0, let itemIndexToRemove = roomNumbers.index(of: validRoom) {
                roomNumbers.remove(at: itemIndexToRemove)
            }

            print("Room Area Not Detected Before Adding Content")

            //b. Add The Plane Anchor To Our Array & Then Generate Our Content
            roomPlanes[roomPlaneAnchor.identifier] = roomPlaneAnchor

            let width = CGFloat(roomPlaneAnchor.extent.x)
            let height = CGFloat(roomPlaneAnchor.extent.z)

            let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: width, height: height))
            sphereNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = colours[roomPlanes.keys.count-1]
            sphereNode.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-Float.pi / 2, 1, 0, 0)
            node.addChildNode(sphereNode)

            detectedRoomNumber = nil

        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully I managed to articulate my idea in a way that makes sense to someone else other than myself :)

And of course, hope it points you in the right direction...

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely take a look at this! In the meantime if you want to see the full code, I just posted another question and the code is there! Btw , you can try and help me with that other problem also :D